# Delphi и устройство чтения карточек с магнитной лентой

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Помогите с дилеммой. Как программе на Делфи вставить в едит символы снятые с карточки с помощью устройства чтения карточек с магнитной лентой?

**Точнее:**  едит - скрыт, а еще стоит таймер. К примеру, если в едите находится, допустим, 8 символов то проверить их в базе, если есть сходство вывести строчку в лейбл, если нет - ожидать ввода.

Comment: Хмпф. Читайте мануал к устройству и документашку к драйверу.
Потом считываете данные и вставляете в едит =D

Comment: а точнее можно

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Ну, сделайте един видимым, если надо. Если есть сходство чего-то с чем-то, выведите в лейбл=)

Comment: Ладно. Я работаю с тачскрином. Вместо клавиатуры поключон картридер. Мне нужно чтобы в первом окне программы указатель всегда находился в едите или при вводе информации она всегда записывалась в едит!

Comment: Т.е. ваш кард-ридер работает как HID-устройство?

Comment: Да, Устройсво напоминает клавиатуру

Comment: Клавиатура и магнитный считыватель информации( как на магнитофонах )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> К примеру если в едите находится допустим 8 символов то проверить их в базе, если есть сходство вывести строчку в лейбл, если нет - ожыдать ввода.

Переопределить OnKeyPress для Вашего Edit'а и там проводить проверку:

1. на достаточность кол-ва введенных символов;
2. если символов достаточно - поиск в базе;
3. если есть символы, ввод которых нужно не допустить - можно сравнивать вводимое с шаблоном и если символ запрещен, то игнорировать его ввод
4. и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, это терминальная машинка будет? ) Тогда лучше всего ставить хук (если картридер HID) либо может быть ком порт, тогда курим доки к картридеру и читаем данные из порта, и отключать стандартный шэл (заменить explorer на свой софт). Далее не нужен вам эдит, храните данные в строках (тем более, если получать через хук). О хуках неплохие статьти с примерами есть на DRKB.ru.

Проверять картридеры стоит не по длине, а по символу #13, т.к. все они завершают ввод им (в случае HID). Если будут доп вопросы обращайтесь в скайп (torch565), у самого есть софт, который работает с магнитыми картами и штрих ридерами, поделюсь нароботками.